# JSON undefined cuando lo traigo de una funcion al modulo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Un poco de contexto, tengo un view donde importo mi archivo js "bill-control.js" como un modulo.

Dentro de ese bill-control, importo otro archivo donde hay funciones, se llama, "dinamic_search_mp.js".

Allí, por ahora, solo hay una funcion que posee el mismo nombre, lo que hace es una busqueda dinamica utilizando un archivo php del mismo nombre.

La funcion dinamic_search_mp, del dinamic_search_mp.js recibe como parametro una letra y el php para la busqueda recibe por $_POST el parametro solicitado (una letra), este realiza la busqueda en la BD y genera un JSON que se lo devuelve a dinamic_search_mp.js

dinamic_search_mp.js debe pasar ese JSON al controlador (bill-control.js), pero, cuando intento ver esa repuesta, me dice que es undefined. Pero haciendo un console.log en dinamic_search_mp.js del resultado, me figuran los datos correspondientes.

adjunto los codigos:

```
//control-bill.js
$('#nombre_producto').keyup(function(){
    console.log("input product_name");
    let search= $('#nombre_producto').val();
    console.log('Repuesta del controller: '+dinamic_search_mp(search));
})

//funcion dentro del archivo dinamic_search_mp.js
export function dinamic_search_mp(mp){
let search = mp;
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../../model/materia_prima/dinamic_search_mp.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {search},
        success: function(response){
            console.log('response app: '+response);
            let json = JSON.parse(response);
            
            return json;
        }
    })
```

}

//archivo php en la carpeta dinamic_search_mp.php

$resultado['nombre'], 'id_mp' => $resultado['id_mp']);
        }
        $jsonString = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonString;

    }
?>

El php no tiene ningun problema, se que es inecesario el while ya que unicamente quiero un solo registro pero probé de hacerlo de ambas formas por un ejemplo anterior donde si funcionaba.

El archivo donde esta la funcion creo que tampoco tiene ningún problema aparente porque en ese console.log, me da los datos.

El problema es en el bill-control.js que en la consola me muestra undefined

[image: Esta es una captura de la consola]

Comment: Saludos. Lo que ocurre es que la ejecución de `dinamic_search_mp` finaliza sin nada definido (el `undefined` que recibes) pues lo ùltimo que se ejecuta es el **$.ajax** pero sin esperar este termine. Acorde a tu lógica deberàs ya sea en el 'done'  o ' fail` del **ajax** procesar el resultado (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ o también el `error`, `success` o `complete` según consideres o estes más familiarizado) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema, como apunta @RobertoLeOr es que la función `dinamic_search_mp` acaba *antes* de que la respuesta de `ajax` finalice. Sin ningún `return`, devuelve `undefined` por defecto.

Debes lidiar con el asincronismo, es decir, "esperar" a obtener la respuesta del servidor para poder continuar con tu ejecución.

Para ello, `dinamic_search_mp` debe retornar una `Promise`.

```
export function dinamic_search_mp(mp) {
  const data = mp;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../../../model/materia_prima/dinamic_search_mp.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data,
      success: function(response) {
        const json = JSON.parse(response);
        // Resolvemos la Promise con
        // la respuesta del servidor
        resolve(json);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Des de la función donde invoquemos a `dinamic_search_mp`, deberemos usar `then` para "esperar" esa llamada.

```
$('#nombre_producto').keyup(function() {
    const search= $('#nombre_producto').val();
    dinamic_search_mp(search).then(response => {
        // En este punto recibimos la respuesta.
        console.log('Response', response);
    });
})
```

---

Deberás pensar, también, en el manejo de errores. ¿Qué pasa cuando la llamada no resulte bien?
Para ello, en vez de resolver la `Promise` con `resolve`, la resolveremos con `reject`.

```
export function dinamic_search_mp(mp) {
  const data = mp;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../../../model/materia_prima/dinamic_search_mp.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data,
      success: function(response) {
        const json = JSON.parse(response);
        // Resolvemos la Promise con
        // la respuesta del servidor
        resolve(json);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        // "Marcamos" la Promise con error.
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

> Se puede reescribir de una forma más concisa: `error: reject`

Y, des de la función que invoca a la `Promise`, nos suscribimos también al error con la función `catch`.

```
$('#nombre_producto').keyup(function() {
  const search= $('#nombre_producto').val();
  dinamic_search_mp(search)
    .then(response => {
        // En este punto recibimos la respuesta.
        console.log('Response', response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // En este punto recibimos el error. then() no se ha invocado
      console.error('Error', error);
    });
})
```

---

Por último, y sólo como apunte. Es "peligroso" y poco eficiente hacer una llamada al servidor por cada tecla pulsada (en lo que me imagino que será un `input`).
Te recomiendo que hagas una estrategia de *timeout* para hacer la llamada sólo cuando el usuario lleva X milisegundos sin escribir nada.
Pero eso será mejor que lo pruebes tú mismo y si no te sale, abrir otro *post* para ello.

Espero que sirva.